How to prevent "OperationalError: Database is locked" from discarding changes?
I have an application that periodically records data to a database with Python's SQLite3. Unfortunately, when I open the database with DBBrowser, it can sometimes lock the database. When this happens, cursor.commit() will discard changes when OperationalError: database is locked is raised. Is there any way I can "save" these changes until the database is free again? Such as continually rolling them into the next cursor.commit()?
To be clear, I'm not asking why the database is locked or how to prevent it - its because of DBBrowser. I'm asking if there's a way I can prevent it from discarding changes. Whether that be directly through sqlite somehow, or some other way of manually storing and re-attempting each command.
EDIT: per request in the comments, here's a simple example I tested to make sure it was discarding like I thought. It just increments a counter and pushes it every 10 seconds. After a few seconds, I opened DBBrowser to make it lock up, then I closed it.
con = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cur = con.cursor()
i = 0

while (True):
    try:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(?)", (i,))
        con.commit()
        print(f"committed i={i}")
    except sqlite3.OperationalError as e:
        traceback.print_exception(e)
    i += 1
    print(f"i={i}")
    time.sleep(10)

And here is the log output
committed i=0
i=1
committed i=1
i=2
committed i=2
i=3
committed i=3
i=4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "l:\Coding\Python\sqlite3test\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(?)", (i,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
i=5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "l:\Coding\Python\sqlite3test\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(?)", (i,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
i=6
committed i=6
i=7
committed i=7
i=8

And the database contains 1, 2, 3, 6, 7

Have you tried putting a try/catch block around the commit call?

@JohnGordon yes

Show us the code you tried, and show us the full error traceback message.

@JohnGordon Done. See edits.

When you catch the exception, you need to try the insert again with the same data.  But you're incrementing i whether it worked or not, so the failed value of i is lost.

In this example, the statement i += 1 belongs inside the try block, so that it is only executed upon a successful commit.

Well that sort-of works for this example, but in my actual application, the data comes from an external source, so its going to try to write different data every time anyway. Plus, if you re-insert (without committing) in the try, then both of those changes will be discarded next time, and only the most recent one will be re-applied.

the data comes from an external source, so its going to try to write different data every time anyway I don't understand why "an external source" is any different.  The answer is to keep re-trying the insert with the same data until it succeeds.
